# Suppress "yourdomain.com could not be found" dialog in GeckFX45

Tags: c#, wpf, geckofx

I am using GeckFX45 from NuGet to host a webpage for my OAuth2 login, During testing its behavior without internet connection I noticed that I get a dialog generated by the browser saying the URL could not be found. How can I suppress this to I can catch and handle the scenario in my app without alerting user?

My browser code is pretty standard, but for arguments sake included here anyway (Note I am using WPF not Win Forms hence the host control):

```
    public OAuthLogin2(OAuthActions action, string args = null)
    {
        this.action = action;

        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
        host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        browser.DocumentCompleted += Browser_DocumentCompleted;
        browser.Navigating += Browser_Navigating;

        browser.NavigationError += Browser_NavigationError;
        browser.NSSError += Browser_NSSError;

        InitializeComponent();

        host.Child = browser;
        GridWeb.Children.Add(host);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe you should detect if there is an internet connection and warn the user about that?

Comment: @wp78de Plenty of things can cause this error that are not related to internet connection.

Comment: Sure. My comment was just a guess. I would love to see a full answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can add a `PromptService`, but this may not work depending on language;

```
    public class NoPromptService : PromptService
    {
        public override void Alert(string dialogTitle, string text)
        {
            log.Warn(dialogTitle, new Exception(text));
            if (text.EndsWith("could not be found. Please check the name and try again."))
            {
                // Do Whatever
            }
        }
    }
```

Add this in constructor:

```
PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new NoPromptService();
```